# Why was this "realistic map" question reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This question – [Is my map realistic?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/227467/is-my-map-realistic) – was closed for being too vague and/or opinion-based. The asker was advised to clarify the nature of the question and provide necessary information. The asker also displayed (in comments and a deleted answer) a willingness to accept all sorts of feedback without any specific focus, effectively subverting the SE format and turning the question into an Infinite List of Things on any given aspect (geography, weather, environemnt, city placement, "etc") someone may glean from the map.

So why was it reopened without any edits from the question asker or explanation from mods? There are now four replies, one with over 20 upvotes, which would be invalidated if the asker were to actually narrow the focus or provide additional information as required by the site.

Comment: I know we're quick to VTC in wb.se, but the alternative is abuse of the site and questions stuck in limbo due to invalidated answers.

Comment: "*The asker also displayed (in comments and a deleted answer) a willingness to accept all sorts of feedback without any specific focus*". I've read the current question and old one, doubt they asked "all sorts of feedback without any specific focus". Yes, they thanked for "any *help*", but it's in regard to the question "is my map realistic?". That's a nuance to take into account. Otherwise, yes, it could be more explanatory, though not enough to trigger my close vote.

Comment: @Tortliena Given that realistic is a pretty subjective question and level of scrutiny is relative just showing a map and asking "Is it realistic" is an underdefined question. Is this map showing up in the background for a few seconds or are you telling a story where mountain formation and prevailing wind patterns are integral to the story. You could also judge a map as unrealistic based on the mapping technology available in the world, if the map is treated as an in world artifact. If you want to know if your rivers don't violate any obvious rules, you should specifically ask for that.

Comment: No mods were involved in the reopening. Any user with the appropriate privilege can see who voted to reopen it in the question chronology.

Comment: @sphennings I think it's fair enough to consider realistic as "in tune with our knowledge of the world, using Earth as reference", especially when considering "realistic" as "believability in its context", since geography is an integral part of a world and the way you build them, so regardless it's shown only 2s in the background, it's more than likely to have impact on everything else ^^.[...]

Comment: @L.Dutch There used to be a time when mods would be more active in closing, and reopening questions. Now it seems like mods will remark on a post not complying with site policy and leave it to the voting members to argue over whether or not to take action. I've seen other sites on the network where mods are still proactive about this. What changed on WB?

Comment: [...] Annnyyyhooww... We should scale what details are needed on what is asked in a typical reality-check (because that's what it is), in order to not be led astray and keep answering about the most glaring issues (typically the best answer in reality-checks). [...]

Comment: [...] In this case, they were quite visible (water sources, city supply lines...), so I'm setting my details threshold lower than others map questions. But the above's dependent on viewpoint, and I still agree that the more precise your question is, the better it would be. From my eyesight, it was a "could be better but it could work" question.

Comment: @Tortliena Remember that simply by choice a worldbuilder can have whatever map they choose. They are the ultimate arbitrators of what rules they want to impose on themselves. Who are we to decide that someone needs to impose more restrictions upon their world. It's similar to how SO answers programming questions but doesn't do code review. One is specific, "How do I solve X problem?" the other is open ended, stylistic and subjective "How could I modify, or improve my code?"

Comment: @sphennings That's supposing that said person has enough knowledge about worldbuilding. If someone doesn't have that skill, then they can only ask genuinely. Not that it allows to not make research on the topic, nor that the question shouldn't be closed (until it can be answered reasonably, which it could here) or downvoted (until some research has been made). Also, please recall that this question is a reality-check with only yes/no answers against our reality (realistic without provided context) with yet some hints of what is looked for (weather, cities, environment...).

Comment: @Tortliena None of the answers are a simple yes or no. They all seem to take a different path to assessing the map. Some answers remark on city placement, some remark on scale, some remark on the shapes of the mountains, some remark on rivers. As written each of these assessments would be an equally valid answer on it's own. This makes for a very broad question, where we're more offering a critique than answering a specific question.

Comment: @L.Dutch I now see there was a re-open vote, but again without any significant edit or focus given the the question (which you yourself agreed was reason to keep it closed), so my question here remains. (I also see a message claiming I've "retracted" my VTC, which I did not do.)

Comment: @Tortliena The map is missing essential information to even begin formulating answers to any of the various directions the OP suggested. Is this an island the size of Hawaii or a continent the size of Europe? Are you assuming the Sea of Ice is polar and not at the equator? How do we say the biomes/climate are realistic without knowing where it is?

Comment: @Tortliena The question is so broad one answer so far concerns itself entirely with the placement of cities while another speculates as to the tectonic history. Both answers may be right about their individual point, but both can't be accepted, therefore it's too broad.